# Copying a file in multiple folders using Batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, command-prompt

I have a PDF `.COMInterop and C# Notes - Notes 1 to 10.pdf` kept in the directory `D:\Dropbox\Sample C# Notes`

The folder `Sample C# Notes` also has some subfolders like 0001, 0002, 0003 and so on till 0100.

I am writing the following command in a batch file to copy the pdf from `Sample C# Notes` to all the subfolders inside it (0001, 0002, 0003...)

```
for /D %%x in (D:\Dropbox\Sample C# Notes\*.*) 
DO COPY D:\Dropbox\Sample C# Notes\.COMInterop and C# Notes - Notes 1 to 10.pdf %%x\.COMInterop and C# Notes - Notes 1 to 10.pdf
```

But it gives an error saying The system cannot find the file specified. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Try to put double quotes around the filename : `"D:\Dropbox\Sample C# Notes\.COMInterop and C# Notes - Notes 1 to 10.pdf"`

Comment: I still get the same error 

for /D %%x in (D:\Dropbox\Sample C# Notes\*.*) 
DO COPY "D:\Dropbox\Sample C# Notes\.COMInterop and C# Notes - Notes 1 to 10.pdf" %%x\".COMInterop and C# Notes - Notes 1 to 10.pdf"

Comment: And why do you think the folder in the parentheses does **not** need double quotes?

Comment: tried that too. says invalid syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File/folder names with spaces **always** need to be double quoted.

```
for /D %%x in ("D:\Dropbox\Sample C# Notes\*") DO (
  COPY "D:\Dropbox\Sample C# Notes\.COMInterop and C# Notes - Notes 1 to 10.pdf" "%%x\"
)
```

or

```
PushD "D:\Dropbox\Sample C# Notes\"
for /D %%x in (*) DO (
    COPY ".COMInterop and C# Notes - Notes 1 to 10.pdf" "%%x\"
)
PopD
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks a ton!